# Where am I going wrong in the column width?

Tags: tables, column-width

I'm trying to create a table that has different column widths. This is what I have so far.

```
\usepackage{graphicx} %to scale table

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered "X" column

\usepackage{lscape}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=2.3\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\hsize=.9\hsize}X}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a bit of visual "breathing space"
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|s| s| b|}
\hline
\textbf{Score} & \textbf{ Description } & \textbf{Assessment criteria}  \\\hline
1 & Description 1 & Really long description that is longer than 3 lines  \\
\hline
2 &  Description 2 & Really long description that is longer than 3 lines    \\
\hline
3 & Description 3  &  Really long description that is longer than 3 lines\\
\hline
4 & Description 4 &  Really long description that is longer than 3 lines \\
\hline
5 &  Description 5 &Really long description that is longer than 3 lines \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Criteria used}
\end{table}
```

This is the result I get:
[image: Result]

How can I remove the extra column on the right side and make the column description wider to fit with its column? I tried changing the values for width of column but it is not working and I get the same result.

**Edit:** I'm using the ACM latex template, i.e the acmart document class.

**Edit 2:** I get this image after using the suggestions of @David Calisle and @daleif

[image]

Comment: your values add up to 3.5 but they must add up to 3 if you have 3 X, but I think you want the first to columns to be set natural width so use `llX`

Comment: Please make your example compilable. Does this example even produce the image shown and without compilation errors.

Comment: My example is for a latex template that uses two columns. I'm sorry, I should have included that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm using the ACM latex template which has two columns on a page. Can you please explain what you mean by 11X?

Comment: @daleif, my example is compilable..that's how I got the image.

Comment: Don't use s s b like here. Just use l l X.

Comment: Your exams me is not compilable. I cannot copy this and test as is. I have to add stuff. That is not a good example

Comment: When I use | | X, I get the image I have updated in the question. I update it there as I cannot add it in the comment.

Comment: It reads el el X and I listed no vertical lines. Similar to Zarkos answer

Comment: sorry `llX` not `11X` where you have used `ssb` or if you want rules then `|l|l|X|`

Comment: The example code you have posted is _not_ complete and does not produce any output, it is missing `\documentclass` \begin{document}` at least. Please make it easy for people to see your issue and not have to guess how you made a working document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Please, extend your code snippet to complete small document with your table.

Comment: @Zarko, thank you. Next time I have a question I will make sure to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your table on the following way:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a bit of visual "breathing space"
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|l|L|}
\hline
\textbf{Score} & \textbf{Description } & \textbf{Assessment criteria}  \\\hline
1 & Description 1 & Really long description that is longer than 3 lines  \\
\hline
2 &  Description 2 & Really long description that is longer than 3 lines    \\
\hline
3 & Description 3  &  Really long description that is longer than 3 lines\\
\hline
4 & Description 4 &  Really long description that is longer than 3 lines \\
\hline
5 &  Description 5 &Really long description that is longer than 3 lines \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Criteria used}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}}
```

[image]